# Broadcasting 3d arrays for elementwise multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting

Good evening,

I need some help understanding advanced broadcasting with complex numpy arrays.

I have:

array A: 50000x2000

array B: 2000x10x10

Implementation with for loop:

```
for k in range(50000):
    temp = A[k,:].reshape(2000,1,1)
    finalarray[k,:,:]=np.sum ( B*temp , axis=0)
```

I want an element-wise multiplication and summation of the axis with 2000 elements, with endproduct:

finalarray: 50000x10x10

Is it possible to avoid the for loop?
Thank you!

Comment: If `B` was (2000,100) you could use `np.dot`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For something like this I'd use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which makes it pretty easy to write down what you want to happen in terms of the index actions you want:

```
fast = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A, B)
```

which gives me the same result (dropping 50000->500 so the loopy one finishes quickly):

```
A = np.random.random((500, 2000))
B = np.random.random((2000, 10, 10))
finalarray = np.zeros((500, 10, 10))
for k in range(500):
    temp = A[k,:].reshape(2000,1,1)
    finalarray[k,:,:]=np.sum ( B*temp , axis=0)

fast = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A, B)
```

gives me

```
In [81]: (finalarray == fast).all()
Out[81]: True
```

and reasonable performance even in the 50000 case:

```
In [88]: %time fast = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A, B)
Wall time: 4.93 s

In [89]: fast.shape

Out[89]: (50000, 10, 10)
```

---

Alternatively, in this case, you could use `tensordot`:

```
faster = np.tensordot(A, B, axes=1)
```

which will be a few times faster (at the cost of being less general):

```
In [29]: A = np.random.random((50000, 2000))

In [30]: B = np.random.random((2000, 10, 10))

In [31]: %time fast = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A, B)
Wall time: 5.08 s

In [32]: %time faster = np.tensordot(A, B, axes=1)
Wall time: 504 ms

In [33]: np.allclose(fast, faster)
Out[33]: True
```

I had to use `allclose` here because the values wind up being very slightly different:

```
In [34]: abs(fast - faster).max()
Out[34]: 2.7853275241795927e-12
```

Comment: An alternative but slower than tensordot is `result = A @ np.transpose(B, (1,0,2))`. It is roughly the same speed as the einsum solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(A[:, :, None, None] * B[None, :, :]).sum(axis=1)
```

But it will blow up your memory for the intermediate array created by the product.

The product has shape `(50000, 2000, 10, 10)`, thus contains 10 billion elements, which is 80 GB for 64 bit floating point values.